# Is it possible to restore DB and keep security permission for login from previous DB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I need to restore the database from a different environment where different logins are used but I want to keep permission to this database for already existing login on this server.

Now, after restoring my login on the targeted server it lost mapping for this database (and owner role) 
I want to restore everything inside the database and same time I don't want to map the database and add owner role to the login.

Is it even possible?

I've tried different ways of restore - deleting before restore, as well as delete but not to close existing connections. The result is the same, I need to map new restored DB again and add the owner role.

Comment: Are these SQL Logins? Do they have the same SID? If the answer is no, from SQL Server's point of view, they are different logins. The name is not the identifier apart from when the user passes the username. From a User -> Login mapping perspective it's the SID that's important.

Comment: On a different note, SQL Server 2008 is now completely unsupported, as has been for several months. You should really be looking at upgrade paths as soon as possible.

Comment: This are different SQL logins, but I restore DB to server where base with same content except logins was already. So I wanted to keep permission from old one.
Im not sure if this is enough information you asked?

Comment: I think i get it now. Seems to be no simple way for that - always require more then I want so login change is best option for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Normally database `users` have to be mapped to instance `logins` to work, but if you want to make your DB more instance independent and control your database from the inside of it then the solution for you would be a [Contained Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15).

From MS BOL:

> A contained database is a database that is isolated from other
>   databases and from the instance of SQL Server that hosts the database.
>   SQL Server 2017 helps user to isolate their database from the instance
>   in 4 ways.
>
> - Much of the metadata that describes a database is maintained in the    database. (In addition to, or instead of, maintaining metadata in the 
>     master database.)
> - All metadata are defined using the same collation.
> - User authentication can be performed by the database, reducing the    databases dependency on the logins of the instance of SQL Server.
> - The SQL Server environment (DMV's, XEvents, etc.) reports and can act    upon containment information.

Comment: I think this is exactly opposite of what I want.

Comment: In that case I need you to elaborate on "different logins are used but I want to keep permission to this database for already existing login" and "after restoring my login". You have 2 environments 2 different sets of logins. You're restoring the database along with their users, where these users should be applied on your second instance if there are no corresponding logins (based on "different logins are used")

Comment: I think this is exactly opposite of what I want.
But I understand it now. Thank you for help